# Dataset to apply Sobol Indices

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, uncertainty, sensitivity-analysis, sobol-indices

I am working on a project based on Sobol indices. I am looking for a dataset to apply Sobol indices. I need to show a basic demonstration of this method. Specifically, I want to identify which inputs are most important to the output.

Would you please guide me with a real-life dataset where Sobol's method is applicable?